# jquery+coffeescript select option by text

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

i have a dropdown list and want to set the default option by its text(not value), the drop down list is:

```
<select class="size">
  <option value="0">size0</option>
  <option value="1">size1</option>
  <option value="2">size2</option>
</select>
```

i want to set the default value to size1, and i tried the following code but none of them works:

```
$(@el).find('.size>option').filter(=>$(this).text() == 'size1').prop('selected', true)
$(@el).find('.size>option[text="size1"]').attr('selected', true)
$(@el).find('.dimension_post option[text="size1"]').attr('selected', true)
```

thanks

Comment: Does the common selector find the `<option>`s -- `$(@el).find('.size>option')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`:contains()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to find an element by its text content.

Assuming `$(@el).find('.size > option')` finds the `<option>`s:

```
$(@el).find('.size > option:contains(size1)').prop('selected', true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FU6xw/

Comment: what if i want to select by exact text? for example if there are two optiosn: size1 and size11, then the above wont' work correctly